# I get errors when I run "bundle install" on zsh

Tags: ruby

I'm having an error messages with trying to run "bundle install". My ruby version is 2.2.0. Also, I installed it with rvm and did an "rvm use" command to change it from 2.4.0 to 2.2.0 because I thought it might fix the error. Anyway I need your help. Much appreciated.

I currently have 3 versions of ruby : 2.2.3, 2.2.0, 2.4.0

My OS MAC OS Sierra 10.12.3

My shell is zsh.

```
/Users/root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not installed gem `bundler`. Try:

```
gem install bundler
```

then `bundle install` again.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I went ahead and run "gem install bundler" and got this error 'gem install bundler
\WARNING:  You don't have /Users/root/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.6
1 gem installed '

Comment: It is a warning, not error. Have you run `bundle install` successfully?

Comment: No, When I run it. I get this error ` /Users/root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /Users/root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
 from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
 from /Users/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 from /Users/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' `

Comment: According to your previous response, you don't have the necessary PATH, use this command to add this to your environment variables: `export PATH="/Users/root/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:$PATH"`. Try this and rerun the two commands.

Because you have multiple ruby versions, replace `2.4.0` in this command with the version you want to use. Use `rvm use -your-desired-version` after add PATH and then run the two commands.

Comment: Also, discovered something I think might be helpful. I tried installing bundler with --verbose and saw that one link doesn't work. I get ' Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.repo.release.site.corp
HEAD http://repo.release.site.corp/internal/rubygems/api/v1/dependencies ' I get a 404 error on it. Think it has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the issue was. But going into my .gemrc file and deleting

```
install: "--user --no-document"
update: "--user --no-document"
```

solved the problem